# Take axis where third axis has max value

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of `n` stacked 2d matrices, here `n = 3`:

```
[[[-1, 90],
  [-2, 50],
  [-3, 10],
  [-3, 40]],

 [[-4, 99],
  [-5, 40],
  [-6,  5],
  [-3, 50]],

 [[-7,  0],
  [-8,  0],
  [-9, 60],
  [-3, 55]]]
```

I want to return a 2d matrix whose rows are the rows where the 2nd column of the `n` stacked matrices have the max value.

For the above array the expected output would be:

```
[[-4, 99],
 [-2, 50],
 [-9, 60],
 [-3, 55]]
```

I tried using the built-in `np.max` but that will return the max along both columns, ie:

```
[[-1, 99],
 [-2, 50],
 [-3, 60],
 [-3, 55]]
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. Can you clarify how you got last 2 entries of your expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
out = a[np.argmax(a[...,1], axis=0), np.arange(a.shape[1])]
```

Output:

```
array([[-4, 99],
       [-2, 50],
       [-9, 60],
       [-3, 55]])
```

Intermediate steps:

```
# get last column
a[..., 1]

array([[90, 50, 10, 40],
       [99, 40,  5, 50],
       [ 0,  0, 60, 55]])

# get idxmax of axis 0
np.argmax(a[...,1], axis=0)

array([1, 0, 2, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Unfortunately this is not what I was looking for. If you check my desired output and your proposed output you will see the difference. This is returning the matrix with the highest value in the last column.

Comment: @alxk my bad, I misread, this is however doable with the same logic, let me update

Comment: @alxk is the final order of the rows important?

Comment: Yes, in this case the order needs to be maintained.

Comment: The the second part of my answer is needed, let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thank you for the effort, this does work on the example initially provided but seems to break when number of matrices != number of rows in each matrix (see updated example, and apologies for not making that clearer at first).

Comment: @alxk sorry, see update!